# What is a good academic word for "verifiable by scientific data or experiments"? Is "empirical" a suitable word for that?

Tags: writing-style

What is a good academic word for verifiable by scientific data or experiments?

Is *empirical data* a suitable word for that?

P.S EDIT: my question is what is A single word for "derived through experimental data" (opposite to derived through observation)

I mean that word should explain that it can be precisely reproduced by others as well because it's experimental data.

Comment: FYI empirical is a very general term. It just means verifiable through observation. Has no experimental connotation. So if you interviewed people about their experiences, that is still empirical data.

Comment: With a slight detour into philosophy, not everyone agrees that "verifiable" is a good criterion. Do other description of what you want to do to your mind?

Comment: Perhaps you could include an example sentence?

Comment: The three examples you give are not of the same concept. You are asking three different questions.

Answer (score 4):

Data are "derived" from observations. Alternatively said, observations become data when we record them. Otherwise, they remain as observations. By example, the only reason we know what Galileo observed during his observations of the moon is because he recorded his observations in pictures, making them data.

The next step in the chain is to "derive" a result. This involves analysis or interpretation.

In summary, the chain is

- observation - (to written record) -> data
- data - (through analysis or interpretation) -> result

The one word you seek is result.

When you want to further qualify the level of effort taken in making observations, you can use words such as focused, directed, or even scientific as opposed to random or undirected. The phrase "unscientific observations" is not necessarily a "good" way to express the opposite of scientific. So, data obtained from directed observations have perhaps a higher standard than data obtained from random observations.

Suppose instead that you need a qualifying metric that defines the trust that you have in a result that is obtained by the analysis of data from (scientific) experiments or observations. Consider these criteria:

- verifiable - able to be found by others
- certifiable - attestable
- precise - reproducible
- accurate - indistinguishable from truth
- measurable - subject to quantification through observation
- robust - impervious to unpredictable outcomes
- empirical - derived through observation
- first-principled - derived through reasoning

You may make variations. For example, a verifiable and robust result is one that others can readily find and that has no ambiguities. A robustly verifiable result is one where the method that one uses to find the result has no ambiguities.

A result obtained from experimental observations is essentially empirical by nature. First principled reasoning may be used to define the accuracy of the result. Replicate, certifiable experiments are needed to establish the degree of precision on the result.

Comment: my question is what is the word for "derived through experimental data" (opposite to derived through observation)

Comment: Just "experimental". There isn't a separate word for it.

Comment: @Pretty_Girl "Verifiable" through experiments is not the same as "derived" through experiments. Experiments involve observation.

Answer (score 2):

A hypothesis "testable by scientific experiments" would be a "scientific hypothesis."

Comment: Technically. trying to verify an hypothesis through experiments is the *opposite* of the scientific method; you're supposed to construct experiments to *disprove* your hypothesis.

Comment: @nick012000 Well spotted.  I'd call that a typo.